# Post subscribe result skipped

Tags: angular, https, subscribe

In an Angular 8 app I have the following method:

```js
onSubmit() {

    this.mailService.sendMessage().subscribe(
      (res: any) => {
          this.toastr.success('Message Sent');
          this.resetForm();
      },
      err => {
        this.toastr.error('Message Not Sent', res.status);
      }
    );
}
```

The `sendMessage()` function is in a Service component and is as follows:

```js
sendMessage(){
    return this.http.post(environment.apiEndpoint + environment.messageController, this.mailMessage);
}
```

`http` being a `HttpClient` object from `@angular/common/http`.

Incredibly `res` is always skipped, no matter the success or failure of the server comunication, in fact that `res.status` you see in the `err` lambda prints 200 which is the code for a successfull transaction with the server, I already had checked that but printed it nonetheless, just to make sure.

Adding to that, the post is successfully received and managed by the server as is to be expected by the 200 OK response.

[image]

Can Someone tell me what's going on here? Why is `res` being seemingly ignored?

Comment: You should print out `err` in your error handler, not sure where `res` is coming from, seems to be a global variable set somewhere.

Comment: @tkausl, it's a local variable, I edited to stress that. I've used this method many times, it's the first time I'm having this kind of result.

Comment: Its local to the first arrow function, not available in your second one. Hence it's getting `res` from somewhere else.

Comment: @tkausl, this is hw the  rxjs subscribe method works, here is the prototype: `Observable<Object>.subscribe(next?: (value: Object) => void, error?: (error: any) => void, complete?: () => void): Subscription`

Comment: What do you see if you print out `err`, as suggested by @tkausl?

Comment: @ConnorsFan, just `[object Object]`.

Comment: Try `console.log(err)` or `console.dir(err)` or `console.log(JSON.stringify(err))`.

Comment: @ConnorsFan, I already tried console.log, with the same results, I'll try console.dir.

Comment: @ConnorsFan, @tkausl, thanks for your interest, the problem seems to be in the server, it returns `status: 200, ok: false, name: "HttpErrorResponse"` for some reason, I've never seen this kind of response before, so what I can do is to ignore the `res` result (which is null) and use the http status code to create conditional action inside `err`, the codes seem to be returning acurately, for now it will have to do.

Comment: Or use `sendMessage().pipe(catchError(err) => { ... })` and throw the error only if the status is not 200. That should allow to use the subscribe error handler only for the responses that you consider as actual errors.

Comment: @ConnorsFan, yes, that will also do the trick, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is incomplete. You need to map the result. Something like this

```
import { catchError, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

sendMessage(){
    return this.http.post(environment.apiEndpoint +
    environment.messageController, this.mailMessage).pipe(
        map((result) => result), catchError(err => throwError(err))
    )
};
```

This transforms success result.

Note: If your application doesn't have global error handling. You need to catch the error!

It may be that your backend is responding error with the status code 200. Check the server to make sure.